Help With Understanding Conditioning in Banach Match Problem
I'm brushing up on some probability and I'm stuck on why some of my reasoning doesn't add up when thinking about this problem conditionally.
Here's the problem:
A pipe-smoking mathematician carries 2 matchboxes, 1 in his left-hand pocket and 1 in his right-hand pocket. Each time he needs a match he is equally likely to take it from either pocket. Consider the moment when the mathematician first discovers that one of his matchboxes is empty. If it is assumed that both matchboxes initially contained N matches, find the probability that there are exactly k matches in the other box, k = 0, 1, …, N.
I defined an rv X as the # of matches in the other box and then calculated that $P(X=k) = 2 \binom{2N-k}{N}(\frac{1}{2})^{2N-k+1}$ which I believe is the correct solution. When I think about $P((X=k) \cap L)$ where L = event where left box discovered empty first, it makes sense that it should be $\binom{2N-k}{N}(\frac{1}{2})^{2N-k+1}$ (just don't multiply by 2 as I already know which box I'm going to discover empty). But then $P(L) = \frac{1}{2}$ which then implies that $P(X=k | L) =2 \binom{2N-k}{N}(\frac{1}{2})^{2N-k+1} = P(X=k)$ which doesn't intuitively make sense to me. Can someone explain where I'm going wrong here? Thanks!

First of all, intuitively by symmetry, as you discovered algebraically, $~p(L) = 1/2 = p(R).$
Second of all, as you discovered algebraically, but are unable to explain intuitively, the events $~X=k,~$ and $~L~$ are independent events.
If you thought that $~X=k~$ was not independent of $~L,~$ you would have to assume that one of the following two applied:
$$P(X=k) > P(X=k|L) \implies P(X=k) < P(X=k|R). \tag1 $$
or
$$P(X=k) < P(X=k|L) \implies P(X=k) > P(X=k|R). \tag2 $$
By considerations of symmetry, neither (1) above or (2) above is feasible.

To explain (1) and (2) above, consider that
since exactly one of the two events $~L~$ or $~R~$ must occur, you must have that
$P(X = k)~$ must be somewhere in between $~P(X=k|L)~$ and $~P(X=k|R).$

I follow your reasoning but I'm trying to reconcile this with my reasoning for how I computed P(X=k)-there are two ways to pick which box is discovered empty and $\binom{2N-k}{N}$ ways to arrange the first $2N-k$ draws as the last draw (the $2N-k+1$ th draw) must be from the box that is discovered empty. If I am given that the left box is discovered empty first, I struggle to see the difference between $P(X=k \cap L)$ and $P(X=k | L)$ intuitively (because if $P(X=k | L) = P(X=k)$ then the '2' is still there which was supposed to account for the two possible choices of the box discovered first)

@RichardZhang This conditional probability article establishes that $$p( ~A ~| ~B ~) = \frac{p(A \cap B)}{p(B)}.$$  Taking $~A = [ ~X = k ~], B = L,~$ you have that $$p( ~X = k ~| ~L ~) = \frac{p( ~[ ~X = k ~] \cap L ~)}{p(L)}.$$  Please leave a further comment, following this answer, if you have more questions.

I understand by the conditional probability formula why $P(X=k|L)=P(X=k)$ it's just that the way that I computed $P(X=k)$ to begin with incorporated the idea that there are two possibilities for which box is discovered empty first--left or right (why I multiply by 2). I'm having trouble understanding how $P(X=k|L)=P(X=k)$ if the way I computed $P(X=k)$ involved the idea of picking which box is discovered empty (because I don't know if it's left or right). Now, if I'm given information that the left is discovered empty, that doesn't change the probability, which confuses me intuitively.

@RichardZhang If I understand your confusion correctly, you are trying to intuitively explain why $~p(X = k|L) = p(X = k),~$ when $~p( ~[X = k] \cap L ~) = 1/2 \times p(X = k).~$  This is the question that I am focusing on.  Please leave another comment, if this is not your question.  Focusing on this question, and examining my previous comment, the explanation is that to compute $~p(X = k|L),~$ you have to divide $~p( ~[X = k] \cap L ~)~$ by $~p(L).~$

@RichardZhang If I have not answered the question that you are trying to ask, then I ask you to leave another comment.  This time, please try to be as clear as you can what your question is.  If feasible (which it may not be, since your question seems to be intuition-based), please express your question mathematically.

I understand why by the conditional probability formula, $P(X=k|L) = 2P((X=k) \cap L) = P(X=k)$, but the way I computed $P(X=k)$ involved me multiplying by 2 for the possibility of two choices for the empty box (left or right). In other words, the way I computed $P(X=k)$ involved considering the 2 possibilities for the discovered box (left or right), so how could this event then be independent of which box is discovered? I'm not sure if I'm communicating my confusion clearly so I'd be glad to elaborate further. Thank you for the help!

@RichardZhang Perhaps the issue is on what intuitive meaning that you give to the notion of independent events.  Suppose that you are rolling a standard 6 sided die.  Let $~E_1~$ denote the event that the number rolled is even.  Let $~E_2~$ denote the event that the number rolled is $~\leq 2.~$ Then, events $~E_1~$ and $~E_2~$ are regarded as independent because $~p(E_1) = p(E_1 | E_2).$  ...see next comment

@RichardZhang That is, in probability theory, if events $~E_1~$ and $~E_2~$ are independent, this does not mean that the number of equally likely ways that event $~E_1~$ can occur is unaffected by whether event $~E_2~$ can occur.  Instead, what it (intuitively) signifies is that the affect of event $~E_2~$ on the number of equally likely ways that event $~E_1~$ can occur is a proportional effect.  ...see next comment

@RichardZhang With your specific posted question, the effect of the event $~L~$ is to reduce the number of satisfying ways that the event $~X=k~$ can occur by $~(1/2),~$ which is proportional to the fact that $~L~$ itself will only occur $~(1/2)~$ the time.  Again, if this does not answer your question, send me another comment.

If I am understanding you correctly, the definition of independence of two events $A$ and $B$ does not necessarily imply that the occurrence of event $B$ has no effect on the possible outcomes associated with event $A$, but rather that the occurrence of event $B$ has no effect on the overall probability of event $A$ occurring. In the context of this problem, the occurrence of $L$ obviously has an effect on the possible outcomes associated with $X=k$ (reduce by 1/2), but we "normalize" this relative to the probability that L itself occurs (1/2) so it ends up that it is still $P(X=k)$.

I was confused by the '2' in $P(X=k|L)=2 \binom{2N-k}{N}(\frac{1}{2})^{2N-k+1}$ as I had first introduced the '2' in P(X=k) to account for the case of either L or R and seeing it in the result for P(X=k|L) confused me. But after your clarifications, it seems to make sense that P(X=k|L)=P(X=k) by their final expression, but that doesn't mean that the method by which I computed P(X=k|L) involved the need to give two options for which box was discovered (as it did for $P(X=L)$), it just happened that the conditional prob. formula gave the same final answer due to the symmetric scaling effects.
